# MongoDB up-gradation or migration from 3.2.8 to 4.4.10 and 4.4.10 to 5.0.3

Tags: mongodb

I would like to inform you that we are migrating MongoDB from 3.2.8 to 4.4.10 and it has been successfully done without any more issue and problems also when we are restarting service of mongoDB then it is being up with 4-5 minutes and on some version 2-3 minutes. But when we are migrating this mongoDB from 4.4.10 to 5.0.3 then service is taking too long time to start (around 50-60 minutes) and same time is taking on after restart when getting started the service.

So
please help us to resolve this issue. and if do you have any solutions on it so please provide us.
Note: We have tested with 2 os version 1. Amazon Linux-2 2. Cent-OS -7 but showing same response
Thank you for your support in advance.
Lal Chand
DevOps Specialist